# How to call method with optional parameter list in JSF2 / EL 2.2

Tags: java, jsf-2, el, optional-parameters, optional-arguments

any idea how (if even possible) to call java method with optional parameters from JSF page?
Iam using Java 7,JSF 2.1, EL 2.2 (Glassfish 3.1.2). Thanks in advance...

I got this exception

```
javax.el.ELException: /example.xhtml: wrong number of arguments
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments
```

Page example

```
<h:outputText value="#{bean.methodWithParameters('key.en.currentDate', '2012-01-01', '00:00')}"/>
<h:outputText value="#{bean.methodWithParameters('key.en.currentTime', '12:00')}"/>
```

Bean example

```
public String methodWithParameters(String key, Object ... params) {
    String langValue = LanguageBean.translate(key);
    return String.format(langValue, params);
}
```

Properties example

```
key.en.currentDate=Today is %s and current time is %s.
key.en.currentTime=Current time is %s.

key.en.currentDate=Today is %1$s and current time is %2$s.
key.en.currentTime=Current time is %2$s.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Varargs is not supported in EL.

As to your concrete functional requirement, you're approaching this totally wrong. You should not reinvent internationalization/localization in JSF, but instead use the JSF-provided facilities. You should be using `<resource-bundle>` in `faces-config.xml` or [`<f:loadBundle>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/loadBundle.html) in Facelets file for this. This will load the files by [`ResourceBundle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html) API and use the [`MessageFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) API to format the messages. You can then format the strings by [`<h:outputFormat>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/outputFormat.html) with [`<f:param>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/param.html).

E.g. `com/example/i18n/text.properties`

```
key.en.currentDate=Today is {0} and current time is {1}.
key.en.currentTime=Current time is {0}.
```

View:

```html
<f:loadBundle baseName="com.example.i18n.text" var="text" />

<h:outputFormat value="#{text['key.en.currentDate']}">
    <f:param value="2012-01-01" />
    <f:param value="00:00" />
</h:outputFormat>
```

Further I'm not sure if that `en` in the key stands for English or not, but if it indeed stands for the language, then you're making another mistake. The separate languages needs to have each its own `properties` file like `text_en.properties`, `text_de.properties`, etc conform [`ResourceBundle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html) API rules.

#### See also:

- [Java EE 6 tutorial - Providing localized messages](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaxw.html)

Comment: ehm... it was only example (-: I do not like examples like x+y=z so I shape it to internationalization example... my mistake. But I have to say that h:outputFormat sounds good and I just learned something new.

Comment: Since varargs are not supported (confirmed by you), I just have three methods with one/two/three parameters to handle varargs like calls. Not nice but work )-: